# why my absolute path for jpg file doesn't work

Tags: xcode, path

I have checked out a few similar questions and didn't find the answer to my question.

First part of the question is how to write relative path of file. I didn't get this work but let me move the second part at the moment. Since I couldn't get relative path work, so I tried absolute path. Here is the code I use:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/my.name/Documents/TestFour/TestFour/Library/file%d.txt", i]; //where i is 1 or 2
//NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"./TestFour/Library/file%d.txt", i]; //this relative path didn't work, although TestFour.xcodeproj and TestFour are in the same directory and TestFour has child directory Library and xxx.h and xxx.m files
NSString *spath = [path stringByStandardizingPath];
NSLog(@"file is %@", spath);
if (spath) {
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:spath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //continue, and I got myText ....
```

Now I have a jpg file, say myPic.jpg, in the same directory as above file1.txt, i.e., in the Library folder. I want to load this image into a UIImageView, here is my code, but it failed.

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/my.name/Documents/TestFour/TestFour/Library/myPic.jpg";
NSString *spath = [path stringByStandardizingPath];
```

[self._bgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:spath]];

However, I tried a web-based image, which BTW from another related thread, and it worked:
    [self._bgView setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3092/2915896504_a88b69c9de.jpg"]]]];

So I'm confused why I could read the_same_folder_file1.txt but not load the_same_folder_myPic.jpg

And back to the first part, why my relative path didn't work? Not sure if this is related, I was asked and selected the default setting (Group or something like this) when I drag this and other jpg into project. I don't know if I need drag this jpg into the project, but the code didn't work either way, before and after dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed`] will load the file with the given name from the app bundle; what you want is `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile]` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a)).

Also you need to understand that relative file paths work based on the process's current working directory.  Do you know what that is?  If not then you can log it using something like:

```
char cwd[1024];
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
NSLog(@"cwd='%s'", cwd);
```

(You may need to `#import <unistd.h>`).

Perhaps that will help you with your relative path issue.

Comment: Curiosity made me check if `getcwd()` is available.. It is! However it just returns `/`

Comment: @JamesWebster Is that from within a sandboxed app?

Comment: @JamesWebster Hmm, I'm not familiar with sandboxed apps very much, but that will certainly affect relative paths (they will become absolute paths I guess...)

Comment: imageWithContentOfFile did work with my JPG absolute path! Thanks. Need take a look of relative path now.